# Which phrase is correct? "tend the sick" and "tend to the sick"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I checked the dictionaries. It seems "tend the sick" should be the correct phrase, but I also noticed the native English speakers said "tend to the sick" or "tend to the young."

Answer (score 2):

Either is correct, but as you observe “tend to” is more commonly used.